# Under what scenarios does it make sense to configure multiple AWS VPC Endpoints for a single RestAPI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I can't figure out what kind of scenarios need more than one VPC endpoints for a single RestAPI.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html#associate-private-api-with-vpc-endpoint

```
aws apigateway create-rest-api \
    --name Petstore \
    --endpoint-configuration '{ "types": ["PRIVATE"], "vpcEndpointIds" : ["vpce-0212a4ababd5b8c3e", "vpce-0393a628149c867ee"] }' \
    --region us-west-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Associating a VPC Endpoint basically means giving that VPC access to the private Rest API. So if you need to access your Rest API from different VPCs that is the use case.

Reasons for using more than one VPC can for example be to isolate different customer workloads or applications to improve security.